# Is there an adjective beginning with "dis" and connoting non-negative meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests

Out of curiosity, I would like to know whether there is an adjective beginning with "dis" and connoting non-negative meaning?

Comment: how about *discussion* or *discotheque*?

Comment: @Jim:   Right, you got the logical loophole. Haha, I should narrow the range of such words down to adjectives.

Comment: ... discernable

Comment: Good idea! Any else? And what is the etymology of "discernable"?

Comment: ... discoverable - I think there are likely to be a lot of *-able* adjectives

Comment: Distinctive. Disciplined.

Comment: distilled. disseminated. dispersed. Just go through a dictionary.

Comment: @SrJoven: I am sorry, can "disk" be an adjective?

Comment: *Disposed* (at least better than *indisposed*!). Etc. *Di(s)-* in Latin means "apart, away from" and is neither negative nor positive. *Cerno* means "to separate, distinguish, see". To *discern* is to "distinguish apart", i.e. to tell apart.

Comment: Just what do you mean by *connote a non-negative meaning*? Can you explain or give examples of a negative and a non-negative meaning?

Comment: Brian: "disk brakes".  Otherwise cistant, disputable, discarded, displayed.

Comment: Disclosure, discovery, the list is near endless... It would be very interesting to learn where the idea comes from that words starting with _-dis_ usually _have_ a negative connotation.

Comment: _Disyllabic_ (you didn't say anything about morpheme boundaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
discernable
discoid
discontinuous
discreet
dispensable
disproportionate
disputable
disquieting
dissimilar
distal
distant
distinct
distinguishable
distinguished
distortable
distributive
```

all begin dis- and are arguably positive. Feel free to add to it.